# UITextView is jerky

Tags: ios, uitextview

No clue what's going on here. Not sure why it jerks over a little bit each time it becomes active.

Everything is done in the storyboard, no code involved really.

[image]

For context this is in its own viewtable and only has a UITextView.

Comment: Did you set the right constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the constraints like below, it works without jerks.

[image]